# La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy ejecutando un script SQL , donde creo e inserto miles de datos y me arroja este error :

```
La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo.
```

Puede que modificando la linea se solucione , pero en mi caso tengo miles de insert  y no seria factible editar uno por uno

```
INSERT [dbo].[comprobante] ([id], [serie], [numero], [fechaEmision], [fechaVencimiento], [sumTributos], [valorVenta], [descuentos], [otrosCargos], [anticipos], [total], [condicion], [id_cliente], [id_TipoComprobante], [enviado], [generado], [hash], [id_venta], [id_forma_pago], [id_movimiento_caja], [obs]) VALUES (1054, N'FFFF', 26, CAST(N'2019-07-22 15:15:36.753' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2019-07-28 15:15:36.753' AS DateTime), CAST(4.58 AS Decimal(11, 2)), CAST(25.42 AS Decimal(11, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(11, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(11, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(11, 2)), CAST(30.00 AS Decimal(11, 2)), 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, N'0', 3131, 1, 37, NULL)
```

Cuando ejecuto `SELECT SYSDATETIME()`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podria solucionar este error , sin modificar cada linea del insert

Gracias

Comment: verifica el idioma de tu SQL por que posiblemente estas enviado la fecha a lo inverso

Comment: Ayudaría mucho al OP y a tu respuesta si añades el como hacer lo que le propones, checa [answer]

Comment: Gracias, añadí una respuesta para mi caso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que mencionan los comentarios anteriores es correcto , estaba tomando el día como mes y el mes como día , por esa razón me aparecía  valor fuera de intervalo cuando realizaba la conversión.

La **Solucion** que me funcionó:

```
SET DATEFORMAT 'YMD'
```

OBS:

Y: AÑOS
M: MES
D: DIAS

Este formato correponde al formato de la fecha que ingresa

Answer (score 1):

La inserción que estás realizando es correcta.

Realizando lo siguiente, el resultado es el esperado

```
create table #Prueba (ID int identity(1,1), Fecha datetime, Fecha2 Smalldatetime)

insert into #Prueba (Fecha, Fecha2)
select CAST(N'2019-07-22 15:15:36.753' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2019-07-22 15:15:36.753' AS DateTime)
```

El error que te muestra no es en el `INSERT`, es en el `CAST` por lo que me inclino a pensar que tienes algunas fechas con un formato incorrecto. Puede que no sean fechas, puede que esas fechas estén en formato equivocado (por ejemplo aaaa-dd-MM ...). Por ejemplo:

```
select CAST(N'2019-22-07 15:15:36.753' AS DateTime)
```

Si lo datos salen de otra tabla sería conveniente hacer una comprobación previa con la función `ISDATE()`, es decir `WHERE ISDATE(Fecha) = 1` para que solo insertara los registros correctos y luego analizar los incorrectos. Si la fecha es errónea (un varchar que no puede convertirse a fecha) no podrá insertarse.

Por otra parte al hacer el insert no es necesario hacer el `CAST`, puesto que SQL Server lo realiza automáticamente, por lo que el resultado de lo siguiente es idéntico (correcto en las dos primeras sentencias, error en la tercera y cuarta):

```
insert into #Prueba (Fecha) select N'2019-07-23 15:15:36.753'
insert into #Prueba (Fecha) select CAST(N'2019-07-23 15:15:36.753' as DateTime)
insert into #Prueba (Fecha) select N'2019-23-07 15:15:36.753'
insert into #Prueba (Fecha) select CAST(N'2019-23-07 15:15:36.753' as DateTime)
```

Comment: El problema es que aunque sea un formato que concuerde con el estándar ISO 8601, no es un formato universal en SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Este es un problema de configuración de fecha o idioma en SQL Server. El detalle está en que te toma el mes como día y viceversa. Para escribir fechas y horas, sólo hay dos formatos universales: `YYYYMMDD hh:mi:ss.mss` o `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mi:ss.mss` (nota la T entre la fecha y la hora).

Por lo tanto, tus conversiones de fecha podrían quedar con una de las siguientes opciones, ya sea con formatos universales o con código de formato:

```
 CAST( N'20190722 15:15:36.753' AS DATETIME)
,CAST( N'2019-07-28T15:15:36.753' AS DATETIME)
,CONVERT( DATETIME, N'2019-07-28 15:15:36.753', 121)
```